# What does EMBED function mean in Excel Controls?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am adding a button in an existing Excel file. I noticed that the existing buttons has the EMBED formula specified to it. What does the function mean?

```
=EMBED("Forms.CommandButton.1","")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Honestly there really is not much documentation available on this "function". It is one of those things which are exposed unnecessarily when it really shouldn't have been. We are not supposed to enter this manually.

When you select a CommandButton and place it in Excel, you will see

```
=EMBED("Forms.CommandButton.1","")
```

in the Formula Bar. This text is necessary and should not be deleted. It is Excel's way of telling itself that an object has been inserted.

Comment: Is this only for pre-Excel 2007 feature. I tried to add a command button using Excel 2007 and it does not have the embed function, I cannot wire auto functions to it within the sheet.

Comment: No. It is also available in Excel 2007 and 2010 as well. You will only see that function if you are using an ActiveX Control and not a form control.

Comment: While this answer is correct, more information can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31353117/3566998

Comment: I found this answer, which also describes the second parameter: <https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/function-embed.htm>