# What does "=EMBED("Forms.CheckBox.1","")" do for checkboxes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-4.0

I have an Excel sheet with a large amount of checkboxes. I copy and pasted the checkboxes around. In the formula bar, every single one of them has

```
=EMBED("Forms.CheckBox.1","")
```

What is the significance of this? What does it do to the checkboxes?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373348/what-does-embed-function-mean-in-excel-controls) may answer your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In 1993 Microsoft added VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) to Excel with the release of Excel 5.

Prior to that Excel included a completely different macro language, known as XLM (Excel Macros).

XLM macros have a formula syntax, and there is even a special sheet type in Excel for XLM macros called a Macro Sheet. These macro sheets are in addition to the normal worksheets and chart sheets that are more widely used today.

XLM macros still function now, even in Excel 2013.

EMBED() is an XLM function that is used by Excel to embed another OLE application into a worksheet. IT IS NOT PART OF VBA.

The ActiveX controls, of which the checkbox is one, are included with VBA as part of the MSForms 2.0 Object Library.

When you insert any OLE object into a worksheet, Excel uses the XLM EMBED() function to link to that object. As a user, you are not meant to edit this formula directly.

In your case it is linking to the checkbox control in the MSForms 2.0 Object Library.

This allows the checkbox control to actually function in the worksheet instead of on a userform.